# Get the value of some weights in a model trained by TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a ConvNet model with TensorFlow, and I want to get a particular weight in layer. For example in torch7 I would simply access `model.modules[2].weights`. to get the weights of layer 2. How would I do the same thing in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In TensorFlow, trained weights are represented by [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects. If you created a `tf.Variable`—e.g. called `v`—yourself, you can get its value as a NumPy array by calling [`sess.run(v)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) (where `sess` is a [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session)).

If you do not currently have a pointer to the `tf.Variable`, you can get a list of the trainable variables in the current graph by calling [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#trainable_variables). This function returns a list of all trainable `tf.Variable` objects in the current graph, and you can select the one that you want by matching the `v.name` property. For example:

```
# Desired variable is called "tower_2/filter:0".
var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "tower_2/filter:0"][0]
```

Comment: Many thanks @mrry, if I load pertained model from any model zoo support by Tensorflow can I access their trainable parameters with same function I tried but it returned empty matrix. Any answer please

Comment: It depends on the mechanism used for loading the model. If you use the newer `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` then `tf.trainable_variables()` should work. If you use the lower level `tf.import_graph_def()` function, then you should pass the name of the variable in the `return_elements` optional argument, and a tensor will be returned (that you can then pass to `sess.run()`.

Comment: I am sorry to come to ask again. I tried with one convent in audacity https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/4_convolutions.ipynb and I tried to implement your idea like this with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "layer1_weights"] ; Can you please give me the function that I can print the weights?

Comment: Ah, the problem with that model is that the variables don't have meaningful names. You have two options. (N.B. You'll have to use the same session as you used to train the network to retrieve the weights.) 1. Simply execute `session.run(layer1_weights)` after training to get the value of the variable (this is the first suggestion in my answer). 2. Add a `print` statement after `layer1_weights = tf.Variable(...)` to find out TensorFlow's name for that variable (e.g. `print(layer1_weights.name)`), and then use that string to look up the variable in `tf.trainable_variables()`.

Answer (score 20):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: If we build a Model using **`Keras Sequential API`**, we can get the Weights of the Model using the code mentioned below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1

from tf.keras import Sequential

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=conv1_fmaps, kernel_size=conv1_ksize,
                         strides=conv1_stride, padding=conv1_pad,
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(height, width, channels),
                    data_format='channels_last'))

model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides= (2,2), padding="VALID"))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.summary()

print(model.trainable_variables)
```

The Last Statement, `print(model.trainable_variables)`, will return the Weights of the Model as shown below:

```
    [<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 
'dense/kernel:0' shape=(6272, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' 
shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(32, 10) 
dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>]
```

Answer (score 10):

So if you proceed this code step by step, you will first get a list of used/trainable variables. Then you could sort them in a list where you sort weight matrices/lists to variable names, just for example how you were possible to deal with that information.

```
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
print(vars) #some infos about variables...
vars_vals = sess.run(vars)
for var, val in zip(vars, vars_vals):
    print("var: {}, value: {}".format(var.name, val)) #...or sort it in a list....
```

Comment: Always give credit to where it belongs. The ans is given in this [issue](https://github.com/google/prettytensor/issues/6#issuecomment-380919368)

Comment: Also, what is `sess` here? the answer should be self-contained..

Answer (score 3):

`model.weights`

will also do the trick; the same as

`model.trainable_variables`

Answer (score 2):

To get the weights in the form of arrays. This gives all the parameters(trainable and non trainable). Examples of non trainable parameters are moving mean and moving variance of Batch Norm Layer

```
model.get_weights()
```

And then you can access the weights of any layer using

```
model.get_weights()[0]
model.get_weights()[1]
```