# Get weights from tensorflow model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Hello I would like to finetune VGG model from tensorflow. I have two questions.

How to get the weights from network? The trainable_variables returns empty list for me.

I used existing model from here: https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16 .
I find the post about getting weights however this doesn't work for me because of import_graph_def. [Get the value of some weights in a model trained by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np

with open("../vgg16.tfmodel", mode='rb') as f:
  fileContent = f.read()

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)

images = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 224, 224, 3])

tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={ "images": images })
print("graph loaded from disk")

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

cat = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open('../cat224.jpg'))
print(cat.shape)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  print(tf.trainable_variables() )
  sess.run(init)
```

Comment: Try to avoid asking multiple questions at once. If you cannot find an answer to either, and you think they are both valuable questions, feel free to ask both of them in separate posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [pretrained VGG-16 model](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16) encodes all of the model parameters as [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#constant) ops. (See, for example, the calls to `tf.constant()` [here](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16/blob/97a9e1ff663ac7238f986d8b8247f4ab81f83432/caffe_to_tensorflow.py#L88).) As a result, the model parameters would not appear in `tf.trainable_variables()`, and the model is not mutable without substantial surgery: you would need to replace the constant nodes with [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects that start with the same value in order to continue training.

In general, when importing a graph for retraining, the [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#import_meta_graph) function should be used, as this function loads additional metadata (including the collections of variables). The [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#import_graph_def) function is lower level, and does not populate these collections.