# accessing the variable and bias tensor in fully_connected

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I want to save the Variable and bias tensors as checkpoints during training steps . I have used fully_connected() from tf.contrib.layers to implement several fully connected layers . To do so I need to extract the Variable and Bias tensors of those fully_connected layers . How to do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to mention that:

- There is no need to extract weights and biases just to save them. For tf.layers or tf.contrib.layers, if trainable is set to `True`, the weights and biases are added to `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`, which is a subset of `GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`. Thus, if you use `saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.global_variables())` and `saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step)` at some point, the weights and biases will be saved.
- In cases you really have to extract variables, one way would be to use `tf.get_variable` or `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name` with the correct variable name, as mentioned by the other answer.
- You might have noticed TensorFlow classes such as `tf.layer.Dense` and `tf.layers.Conv2D`. Once built, they have `weights` / `variables` methods that return the weight and bias tensors.

Answer (score 1):

The tf.trainable_variables() will give you a list of all the variables in the network that are trainable. This could be made better by using variable_scope and name_scope, like stated here: [How to get weights from tensorflow fully_connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158606/how-to-get-weights-from-tensorflow-fully-connected)

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: a1 = tf.get_variable(name='a1', shape=(1,2), dtype=tf.float32)

In [3]: fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(a1, 4)

In [4]: sess = tf.Session()
2017-12-17 21:09:18.127498: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-12-17 21:09:18.127554: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-12-17 21:09:18.127578: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-12-17 21:09:18.127598: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-12-17 21:09:18.127618: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

In [5]: tf.trainable_variables()
Out[5]: 
[<tf.Variable 'a1:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>]

In [6]: for var in tf.trainable_variables():
   ...:     if 'weights' in var.name or 'biases' in var.name:
   ...:         print(var)
   ...:         
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>

In [7]:
```