# Weights and Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Is it possible to know the weight matrix of a fully trained Neural Network with multiple hidden layers. More specifically, Can we check and store these values for every training iteration.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow - even if nobody understands the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.train.Saver` class provides methods to save and restore models. The `tf.saved_model.simple_save` function is an easy way to build a saved model suitable for serving.

[See Official Documentation Here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration you are passing a `train_op` to `sess.run` asking it to compute that right? Something like this:

```
sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={...})
```

You could also ask it to return other values, such as the `cost` and `accuracy` tensors using something like this:

```
_, result_cost, result_accuracy = sess.run([train_op, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={...})
```

If that all makes sense, then accessing the weight matrix is no more complicated. You just need a reference to the weight matrix tensor (keep it around when you create it or look up the tensor by name):

```
weight_matrix, _ = sess.run([weight_tensor, train_op], feed_dict={...})
```

Notice that you can request the value of any tensor (variable, or operation) along with your training. You can also just call sess.run and ask for that particular value:

```
weight_matrix = sess.run([weight_tensor])
```