# how do i extract conv layer output from tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building a `CNN` model with `tensorflow`. I would like to extract the matrix from the tensor in the first convolution layer conv1.

I can only get its shape:
`Tensor("conv2d_24/Tanh:0", shape=(1, 4, 5, 1), dtype=float32)`

I would like to extract the (4,5) matrix of the output tensor.
How can i do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output from a tensor by running:

```
tensor_name.eval(feed_dict={...})
```

and replace tensor_name with whatever you called your tensor when you first defined it.

Unless you are looking for the weights of this layer? In which case i think this should answer your question: [Get the value of some weights in a model trained by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow)

Comment: what should i put in the feed_dict={..}  please ?

Comment: The same as when you run your train_op...so you probably have some input features that you defined earlier, something like: 

x = tf.variable(...)

so your feed_dict would be feed_dict={x: x_batch}


...Take a look through this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/mnist/beginners