# How to retrieve weights/biases of trained model and assign those to specific layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am currently getting in grasps with TensorFlow and have implemented a basic multilayer perceptron model with 3 hidden layers following the tutorials by sentdex on YouTube.

I was wondering how do I retrieve those trained weights/biases of each layer and if its possible also to assign those retrieved matrices to a specific layer etc. While it probably does not make much sense for me to do this, my aim is just to experiment and see the resulting impacts and get more familiar with TensorFlow.

I have looked at some suggestions to make use of `tf.trainable_variables()` but still can't get my mind around it. The way I can think of is to initialise and then assigning predefined variables to it at the end which could is a little messy if it even works.

```
class expFFNN():

def __init__(self):


    self.nNodesHidL1 = 500
    self.nNodesHidL2 = 500
    self.nNodesHidL3 = 500

    self.nClass = 10
    self.batch_size = 100

    self.x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
    self.y = tf.placeholder('float')

    self.h1Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, self.nNodesHidL1]))
    self.h2Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL1, self.nNodesHidL2]))
    self.h3Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL2, self.nNodesHidL3]))
    self.outWeights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL3, self.nClass]))

    self.h1Biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL1]))
    self.h2Biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL2]))
    self.h3Biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nNodesHidL3]))
    self.outBiases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nClass]))

    self.finH1W = []
    self.finH2W = []
    self.finH3W = []

    self.finH1B = []
    self.finH2B = []
    self.finH2B = []


def neural_network_model(self, data):
    h1Layer = {'weights':self.h1Weights,
               'biases':self.h1Biases}

    h2Layer = {'weights':self.h2Weights,
               'biases':self.h2Biases}

    h3Layer = {'weights':self.h3Weights,
               'biases':self.h3Biases}

    outputLayer = {'weights':self.outWeights,
               'biases':self.outBiases}

    layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, h1Layer['weights']), h1Layer['biases']) 
    layer1 = tf.nn.relu(layer1)

    layer2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer1, h2Layer['weights']), h2Layer['biases']) 
    layer2 = tf.nn.relu(layer2) 

    layer3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer2, h3Layer['weights']), h3Layer['biases']) 
    layer3 = tf.nn.relu(layer3)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer3, outputLayer['weights']), outputLayer['biases']) 

    return output    


def trainNeuralNetwork(self, x):
    y = self.y
    prediction = neural_network_model(self, x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=self.y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hmEpochs = 3

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hmEpochs):
            epochLoss = 0

            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/self.batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(self.batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {self.x:epoch_x, self.y:epoch_y})
                epochLoss += c
            print ('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hmEpochs, 'loss:', epochLoss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        self.finH1W = self.h1Weights
        self.finH2W = self.h2Weights
        self.finH3W = self.h3Weights

        self.finH1B = self.h1Biases
        self.finH2B = self.h2Biases
        self.finH3B = self.h3Biases

        print('Accuracy', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, self.y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: is represented in your model by tf.Variable so just get the weights for all of your layer as a np array and here is the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36193677/2027457

Comment: Please look at `tf.trainable_varaibles()`api.