# Tensorflow classiffier

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm developing a classifier with tensorflow, from a series of variables catalog data in various types, the problem is that I have no vision on which variables are significant...

It is possible to know from the generated model, which variables have been significant? Is it possible to know their weights?

Greetings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of some weights in a model trained by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow)

Comment: You should post the model. If you just use a logistic regression model it is fairly simple

Comment: [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)