# Getting values of trainable parameters in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to extract all trainable weights from a model.
In pytorch a similar thing would be done by a single line `p.grad.data for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad`, however I'm struggling to come up with a simple solution in TF.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
sess = tf.Session()

... #model initialization and training here

p = model.trainable_weights
p_vals = sess.run(p)
```

the last line, however, produces an error:

```
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv1/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv1/bias)
     [[{{node conv1/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm assuming the session/graph doesn't link to the model properly? 
Or is it indeed an initialization problem (but then the model is capable of successfull training)?

Comment: You should be able to see the model weights, without call run method. After the training, simply call model.trainable_weights

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of some weights in a model trained by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow)

Comment: @Giuseppe Angora How do I extract the weight values after that? I need to compute a Fisher information matrix for the weights and for that I need to reach scalar values somehow. When I try to do it with indices I'm getting structures like `<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_13:0' shape=() dtype=float32>`

Comment: @SzymonMaszke No, it recommends the sess.run(p) approach which is currently not working for me (but seems to work ok for the poster. this means I'm implementing it wrong).

Comment: @kravchea What about [Tensorflow Support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60055479/10886420) answer from this post? Are you using `tensorflow2.x`? Keep in mind `tf1.x` is in maintenance mode if you're not and consider a switch if possible.

Comment: I noticed another thing: if I call sess.run with a string argument (for example `sess.run(''conv1/bias:0'')`) I am able to extract the values. Passing the whole model.trainable_weights or tf.trainable_variables() in one bunch seems to cause the described problem however

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I'm using tf1.x due to some legacy code, sadly. Let me check if I can reproduce the bug in tf2.x

Comment: I think I'm not formulating my question clear enough. I am able to get  model.trainable_weights just fine, the result is just not what I need, and I need to come up with another step. How do I extract the **float values** from `<tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>?`

Comment: Ok, it worked in tf2 with the read_value() method. And in tf1.x it worked to get a list of variable names first and then pass it to sesstion (instead of the whole tf.variable object).Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier you do it by using custom callback Fn, and trading with your custom actions follows !

```
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
tf.summary.create_file_writer(val_dir)

def _val_writer(self):
    if 'val' not in self._writers:
        self._writers['val'] = tf.summary.create_file_writer(val_dir)
    return self._writers['val']

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    print('weights: ' + str(self.model.get_weights()))
    
    if self.model.optimizer and hasattr(self.model.optimizer, 'iterations'):
        with tf.summary.record_if(True): # self._val_writer.as_default():
            step = ''
            for name, value in logs.items():
                tf.summary.scalar(
                'evaluation_' + name + '_vs_iterations',
                value,
                step=self.model.optimizer.iterations.read_value(),
                )
            print('step :' + str(self.model.optimizer.iterations.read_value()))

    if(logs['accuracy'] == None) : pass
    else:
        if(logs['accuracy']> 0.90):
            self.model.stop_training = True

custom_callback = custom_callback()

history = model_highscores.fit(batched_features, epochs=99 ,validation_data=(dataset.shuffle(len(list_image))), callbacks=[custom_callback])
```

[image: The weights value from customer callback Fn]