# change a single weight in a NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


# an individual weight is like:
print(model.weights[4][0])
# returns tf.Tensor([0.3985532], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

I'm doing a (somewhat silly) experiment and want to manually deactivate certain neurons in a network. The best way from what I've read is to use a mask, or to adjust weights. For the latter, I can print the value of an individual neuron, but now I want to "set" it. Problem is I can't say tensor = 0.0 because it contains the shape and type as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get the weights as a numpy array this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193553/get-the-value-of-some-weights-in-a-model-trained-by-tensorflow and modify them in that state, then re-set the weights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "assign" to change the values as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


# an individual weight is like:
print(model.weights[4][0])

weights=model.weights[4].numpy() # get the kernel weights of the layer as numpy array
weights[0]=0 #set tensor model.weights[4][0] to zero
model.weights[4].assign(weights)
print(model.weights[4][0]) # displays tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

You can also use "assign" and "tensor_scatter_nd_update" as below:

```
# an individual weight is like:
print(model.weights[4][0])

indices = [[0,0]] #indices to modify 
model.weights[4].assign(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(model.weights[4], indices, [0]))

print(model.weights[4][0]) # displays tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: amazing, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your time!